# Get PHP array values and print in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

I have a table with 9 rows. The first column should print the name of each participant of the ranking. First of, I did an array containing the names of them:

```
$names = array("Mike", "Kyle", "Johnny", "Will", "Vasques");
```

For this task I coded a loop with 5 rows and 10 columns. So, as I mentioned, the first column should print the name of each one.

```
for($x=1; $x<=count($names); $x++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for($td=1; $td<=10; $td++) {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

As you can see, there is a loop for `<tr>` and a loop inside for `<td>`! How do I print each name in the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$names = array("Mike", "Kyle", "Johnny", "Will", "Vasques");
for($td=0; $td<=9; $td++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  if ($td == 0) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
      echo "<td>$name</td>";
    }
  }
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the name first then print 9 more `td`. (Had to change $x to go from `0` to `count($names)-1` to match with indices of `$names`)

```
for($x=0; $x<count($names); $x++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$names[$x]</td>";
  for($td=2; $td<=10; $td++) {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: That works better! Cheers! =D

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop and an [`array_fill`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) for the empty cells

```
// Set the names array.
$names = array("Mike", "Kyle", "Johnny", "Will", "Vasques");

// Set the table cell start key.
$table_cell_start_key = 0;

// Set the table cell count.
$table_cell_count = 9;

// Set the table cells.
$table_cells = implode("", array_fill($table_cell_start_key, $table_cell_count, '<td></td>'));

// Loop through the names array & echo output.
foreach($names as $name) {
  echo "<tr>"
     . "<td>$name</td>"
     . $table_cells
     . "</tr>"
     ;
}
```

The nice thing about using an `array_fill` is you can simple set the values for `$table_cells` ahead of the `foreach` loop. And then the `foreach` loop is just to render content based on the `$names` and the extra table cells are just dropped in.